# window.open('','','location=no') address bar is not visible in ie

Tags: javascript

```
<head>
<script>
function open()
{
win=window.open('','','width=200,height=100,location=no');
win.document.write("<p>This is 'Window'</p>");
win.focus();
}
</script>
</head>
<body>

<input type="button" value="Open window" onclick="open()" />

</body>
```

---

Please copy the above code in an editor and run in your machine(Open
 it in IE    to run).  In the above code the new window is opened when you click on the
     button.The address bar is not visible when 'location' value is set as 'no'.    But it should be disabled when we set location value to
 'no'. expecting the solution

Comment: Not appearing at all sounds pretty disabled to me!

Comment: What is the problem? That the address bar is not visible? And why is that a problem?

Comment: Try `location=yes' or remove it completely.

Comment: "Not appearing at all" is the disabled for IE.

Answer (score 1):

Firefox 3.0 and higher have disabled setting location by default.

For more information see [window.open](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.open)

Even, `Disabled Setting Location By Default`  is supported by all browsers. For the case of IE. It is started with version of IE7.

So, if it is not visible and also it is not lower than IE7. I would suggest you to re-install the browser.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script>
function openWin()
{
myWindow=window.open('','','width=200,height=100');
myWindow.document.write("<p>This is 'myWindow'</p>");
myWindow.focus();
}
</script>
</head>
<body>

<input type="button" value="Open window" onclick="openWin()" />

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I it is not working.....as my requirement.open and see your code in IE.address bar is not visible

Comment: which version of IE? it is working in IE8,9, with any other version?

Comment: hello, you need that the address bar is visible , else url in the address bar? because my code is working in all the IE version , check the example 2 in here http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_open.asp

Comment: Please copy that code in any editor and open with IE.I want the address bar in disabled mode

Comment: I want the address bar in disabled mode not in hiding mode.Please check once.Thanks for Quick response